# questions about using NSURLConnection to download files and show the progress

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios4

I am trying to download files using NSURLConnection and show the download progress.

But I have some limitations and would like to ask if there's any way to solve this.

1. my file needs to be compiled in cpp file.
   for example, I have written this interface to use NSURLConnection

   ```
   @interface DownloadUtil : NSObject
   <NSURLProtocolClient     
   {
       NSMutableData* receivedData;
       NSURLConnection* theConnection;
       long long dataDownloaded;
       long long totalDataSize;
   }
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSData* receivedData;
   @property (nonatomic) long long dataDownloaded;
   ```

But how do I use this interface in cpp file? I initially tried like this

```
class PatchDownload{
   public:
   PatchDownload();
   ~PatchDownload();
   void downloadFile(char* url);
   DownloadUtil* downloadUtil; //has all implementation of all downloading process
};
```

But I get tons of errors telling me that I can' use objective C variables in cpp. 
and the file which contains 'PatchDownload' class is .mm
My first question is that if there's any way to use NSURLConnection in cpp.

1. My second question is that I need to show the progress of the download but when I tried
   'connection:didReceiveResponse' to get the total size of the file being downloaded to calculate the percentage, I got -1. I know that -1 means that 'expectedLength' is undetermined. I would like to ask if there's any way to show the download progress
2. My third question is that if there's anyway to controll the call of 
   'connection:didReceiveData'. For example, I want that delegate to be called every 1000 bytes or other specific bytes. Is it possible to do that?

Thank you very much and I really appreciate your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first question is that if there's any way to use NSURLConnection in cpp.

There should be no problem with having an Objective-C pointer as a C++ class member. My guess is that you are actually including the header file where you declare `PatchDownload` in some other cpp file. Could you check this and if necessary show the error messages (some of them)?

> I would like to ask if there's any way to show the download progress

If the server does not specify the download length, I fear there is no way to show a progress that goes from 0% to 100%. What you could do is show a generic progress, like a spinning wheel when that info is not provided. Of course, if you had access to the server, you could fix this.

> My third question is that if there's anyway to controll the call of 'connection:didReceiveData'.

Unfortunately I don't think so. You should use a lower level api, like [CFStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStreamConstants/Reference/reference.html) which allows to define the buffer size.

Comment: Yes, I include PatchDownload header file in other cpp which will decide whether to download the file or not. And I get literally thousands of errors. Is there anyway to work this out?? Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you add a portion of the compiler output to your question? It would be useful to have a better idea of what is happening...

Comment: I solved problem.. it was because I included objective-c class in c++ class. It took me so long time to find that out. Thank you very much. And if you don't mind, would you tell me that how I can work with server to get the expectedContent? what should I do with server? Thank you again

Comment: I am glad to hear you fixed the cpp problem. About content lenght, it depends on the server; you should ensure the "content-length" header is sent correctly; with apache a cause for it not to be sent is if gzip on-the-fly compression is active... but I have no idea in your specific case what could be...